# Symfony: Overwrite doctrine entity from other bundle

Tags: php, symfony, orm, doctrine

I'm writing a Symfony application which will be used by multiple customers. Some customers require extra functionality, so my idea is that I put all my standard functionality in BundleA, and place extra functionality in BundleB, which is only enabled for customers which require it.

One of the things I want to do in BundleB, is to extend an entity in BundleA, by adding an extra field.

My code currently looks something like this:

```php
<?php
// BundleA/Model/Element.php

namespace BundleA\Model;
use Doctrine\ORM\Mapping as ORM;

/**
 * @ORM\MappedSuperclass
 */
abstract class Element
{
    // All shared fields defined here
}

<?php
// BundleA/Entity/Element.php
namespace BundleA\Entity;

use BundleA\Model\Element as AbstractElement;
use Doctrine\ORM\Mapping as ORM;

/**
 * @ORM\Table(name="Element")
 * @ORM\Entity
 */
class Element extends AbstractElement
{
}


<?php
// BundleB/Entity/BundleBElement.php
namespace BundleB\Entity\Entity;

use BundleA\Model\Element as AbstractElement;
use Doctrine\ORM\Mapping as ORM;

/**
 * @ORM\Entity
 * @ORM\Table(name="Element")
 */
class BundleBElement extends AbstractElement
{
    /**
     * @ORM\Column(name="mypage_id", type="integer")
     */
    protected $mypageId;
}
```

If I try to dump the SQL for the above code, I get the following:

> The table with name 'element' already exists.

Basically what I need I think, is some sort of config option which lets me configure which Element-class to use for the entity. Something like:

```
bundle:
    element_class: BundleB\Entity\BundleBElement
```

but I'm unsure about how to implement such a config option.

All the customers have their own database, so there shouldn't be a issue of conflicting entities.

Comment: Solve one problem first.  You have two entities with the same `@ORM\Table(name="Element")`

Comment: I know. I want both to have the same table name, as only one of them should ever be active. Either it should be configured to use Element from BundleA or from BundleB, never from both. So I want a config option such as "bundle.element_class" which defines which class should be used as the entity.

Comment: It is not as simple as that.  Doctrine2 configuration allows you to specify directories to map.  Bundles are by default mapped automatically if automapping is switched on.  This means you can tell it to ignore one directory and use another.

Answer (score 2):

Your having **two** table definitions. Try to delete the table definition in your Entity or use a different table name.

```
<?php
// BundleA/Model/Element.php

namespace BundleA\Model;
use Doctrine\ORM\Mapping as ORM;

/**
 * @ORM\MappedSuperclass
 */
abstract class Element
{
    // All shared fields defined here
}

<?php
// BundleA/Entity/Element.php
namespace BundleA\Entity;

use BundleA\Model\Element as AbstractElement;
use Doctrine\ORM\Mapping as ORM;

/**
 * @ORM\Table(name="Element")
 * @ORM\Entity
 */
class Element extends AbstractElement
{
}


<?php
// BundleB/Entity/BundleBElement.php
namespace BundleB\Entity\Entity;

use BundleA\Model\Element as AbstractElement;
use Doctrine\ORM\Mapping as ORM;

/**
 * @ORM\Entity
 * @ORM\Table(name="ElementB")
 */
class BundleBElement extends AbstractElement
{
    /**
     * @ORM\Column(name="mypage_id", type="integer")
     */
    protected $mypageId;
}
```

If you wanna extend it, you might delete the table definition in your Entity A so you only have **one** table with the extended data:

```
<?php
// BundleA/Model/Element.php

namespace BundleA\Model;
use Doctrine\ORM\Mapping as ORM;

/**
 * @ORM\MappedSuperclass
 */
abstract class Element
{
    // All shared fields defined here
}

<?php
// BundleA/Entity/Element.php
namespace BundleA\Entity;

use BundleA\Model\Element as AbstractElement;
use Doctrine\ORM\Mapping as ORM;

class Element extends AbstractElement
{
}


<?php
// BundleB/Entity/BundleBElement.php
namespace BundleB\Entity\Entity;

use BundleA\Model\Element as AbstractElement;
use Doctrine\ORM\Mapping as ORM;

/**
 * @ORM\Entity
 * @ORM\Table(name="Element")
 */
class BundleBElement extends AbstractElement
{
    /**
     * @ORM\Column(name="mypage_id", type="integer")
     */
    protected $mypageId;
}
```

Comment: I would prefer to use a single table (Element) as only one of them should be used, depending on the bundles activated. So if BundleB is activated, the Element in BundleA should *not* be used.

Answer (score 0):

What you want is [single table inheritance](http://doctrine-orm.readthedocs.org/en/latest/reference/inheritance-mapping.html#single-table-inheritance):

```
<?php
// BundleA/Model/Element.php

namespace BundleA\Model;
use Doctrine\ORM\Mapping as ORM;

/**
 * @ORM\Entity
 * @ORM\InheritanceType("SINGLE_TABLE")
 * @ORM\DiscriminatorColumn(name="type", type="string")
 * @ORM\DiscriminatorMap({"a"="Element", "b"="BundleBElement"})
 */
abstract class Element
{
    // All shared fields defined here
}

<?php

namespace BundleA\Entity;

use BundleA\Model\Element as AbstractElement;
use Doctrine\ORM\Mapping as ORM;

/**
 * @ORM\Entity
 */
class Element extends AbstractElement
{
}


<?php

namespace BundleB\Entity\Entity;

use BundleA\Model\Element as AbstractElement;
use Doctrine\ORM\Mapping as ORM;

/**
 * @ORM\Entity
 */
class BundleBElement extends AbstractElement
{
    /**
     * @ORM\Column(type="integer")
     */
    protected $mypageId;
}
```

Please note that the `@Table` annotations were removed. (They are actually unnecessary for most use cases. Don't know why people always add them.)